# Can't reach deeper nodes in FirebaseDatabase.net

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is a question about [FirebaseDatabase.net](https://github.com/step-up-labs/firebase-database-dotnet) library

To put this more specifically, I can't reach nodes that are two or more nodes deeper than the root node.
So this for example, this doesn't work:

```
var firebase = new FirebaseClient("https://dinosaur-facts.firebaseio.com/"); 
firebase.Child("dinosaurs").Child("t-rex").PutAsync(new Dinosaur())
```

Because firebase.Child returns ChildQuery object which doesn't have Child method.

I'm using version 3.0.0 installed via NuGet.

If this really doesn't work, is there another way to get the deeper node?

Answer (score 0):

Add this at the top of your class:

```
using Firebase.Database.Query;
```